# Is it meaningful to create a own backend in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, redis, backend

in my project I have different applications that all need a database connection (all "apps" are running on the same server) now my question is, what is better:

one "backend" that get requested from the apps through netty or something and has the one and only mongodb connection and cache with redis

or

all apps have mongodb connection and global cache with redis

Thanks in advance

TG

//edit
all applications are for the same project so they will need the same data

Comment: if your different apps have overlapping/common entities and are using same schema, then it is better to have a common DAO-backend which can be reused by all apps. If your apps are working on different schema and entities, it probably makes better sense to have own connection.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat - Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to write separate Backends for each Application as tomorrow you might want to have different connection requirements from each application.  For eg : One application might decide it doesn't want to use Mongo DB at all . One application might want to use more connections and might be a noisy neighbour for others. Unless you are willing to write a Full Policy based server which can cater to the unique requirements of each application.

Comment: all applications are for the same project so they all need the same data

Comment: @ThomasGleixner That might be true at this moment, but requirements might change and you will be forced to set specific parameters to keep them running. Having backend separated helps you when application need to scale up, for example you can split them into a few servers.